# How to reduce the size of log file with batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have two logs files that are thousands of lines long. I want to have a script that chops off everything except the last, say 51 lines (50 entries, last line is blank).
I have this code:

```
for %%x in (*.log) do (
    for /f "skip=51 delims=*" %%l in ("%%x") do (
        echo. > tmp/%%x
    )
    move /Y tmp/%%x %%x
)
```

but it keeps outputting this (twice, one for each file) and nothing else happens

```
for /F "skip=51 delims=*" %l in ("main.log") do (echo.  1>tmp/main.log )
 move /Y tmp/main.log main.log
)
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

I'm even unsure about the syntax. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\106x"
SET "filemask=*.saved"
FOR %%x IN ("%sourcedir%\%filemask%") DO (
 sed -e :a -e "$q;N;52,$D;ba" "%%x" >"%temp%\x"
 MOVE /y "%temp%\x" "%%x"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

Just a few little things.

First, directory separators are `\` - `/` introduces switches.

Second, `skip=51` will skip the first 51 lines - you want to save the **last** 51.

Native batch could do as you ask - but it would be very, very slow.

I've used `SED` in the above batch, which should be familiar to you, given the syntax you used. It's a 3rd-party utility in the DOS world - I used GNU SED - Google is your friend.

Comment: Wow, thank you Magoo. I ended up using  `"*.log"` in the for command. WORKS LIKE A BOSS!

Answer (score 1):

This uses a helper batch file called `findrepl.bat` - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/rfdldmcb6vwi9xc/findrepl.bat

Place `findrepl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or on the path.

It uses native Windows scripting and is robust and very quick on large files.

```
findrepl  /o:-51 < "file.log"  >"file.tmp" & move /y "file.tmp" "file.log"
```

Comment: Thanks for a portable version since many Windows users dont have sed! +1